# 小塚ゴシックの代替フォント

Tags: css, font

小塚ゴシックをWeb-fontとして使いたかったのですが、adobeでは取り扱っていないようです。

[typekit link](https://typekit.com/fonts/kozuka-gothic-pro)

そこで代わりのフォントを探しています。

無料のもの（クセがなくて、汎用性がありそうなもの）は数が限られていると思います。

探すのに時間が掛かるのは有料のものかと思います。
モリサワ(Type Square)、その他フォント配信サービスで小塚ゴシックと似たものを使える方法などありますでしょうか。

otf, ttfを使うのはIE対応を考えると難しいかなと思っています。

Comment: [teratailでも同じ質問をされているようですが](https://teratail.com/questions/8632)、それぞれのサイトの回答者が互いの回答を参照できるように、そのことを明記されることをお勧めします。

Comment: @unarist そうですね、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[あのフォントがWebフォントに？！有名フォントにそっくりなWebフォントを見つけたよ | 株式会社LIG](http://liginc.co.jp/web/design/font/68373)

という記事で挙げられている Noto Sans Japanese (Source Han Sans Japanese, 源の角ゴシック) はどうでしょうか。

https://typekit.com/fonts/source-han-sans-japanese

Webフォントとして使うなら、[Google Fonts の EarlyAccess版](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess)を使うか、サイズが気になるのであれば自分でサブセット版を作ってwoff等々を生成するとよさそうです。

[【css】NotoフォントをWeb fontとして使ってみよう！（圧縮編） | wd.shortcut](http://wd-shortcut.com/?p=29)

Comment: 参考になりました。
woff変換は無償のものあるのですね。